# children-parenting tag

Tags: discussion, specific-tag

Several questions with the [children-parenting](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/children-parenting) tag have nothing to do with parenting: e.g., [Name of adoptive father in the Ketubah](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9905), [Why only ten? Why not all of Haman's children?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/6449), [Why does "ateres roshi" mean "my parent"?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/11692).

- Should it be renamed [children-parents](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/children-parents)?
- Or should we detag the questions not about parenting?
- Or some other solution?
- Or is the current situation okay?

(Note there's also a [kibbud-av-veim-honoring](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kibbud-av-veim-honoring) tag.)

Answer (score 3):

I think we should remove the tag from questions where it doesn't belong. A "children-parents" tag invites questions about all children and their parents, e.g. the patriarchs, where the question isn't about parenting but just about something involving, say, both Avraham and Yitzchak.  (Do we want to see akeidah questions with this tag?)  I think the intent of the current tag -- parenting, or raising children -- is valuable and shouldn't be diluted.

For the "ateret roshi" question, replacing this tag with the one for kibud av v'eim seems like a good idea.

Comment: I agree with you that parenting should be the exclusive scope of the current tag, but I think there would be value in a tag for the parent-child relationship as well. The _akeda_ would still be out unless the question asked were something like "why couldn't the test have been to kill an innocent stranger?", but questions like [this](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9905/name-of-adoptive-father-in-the-ketubah) could still be in.